# Automatically applying a template (theme) in Silverlight 2 (RC0)

Tags: silverlight, theming, silverlight-2-rc0

Is there a way to automatically apply a theme/template/style to all controls of the targettype, so I don't have to specify Template=..., Style=... on all controls?

Answer (score 2):

I thought there was a way to do this by just omitting the x:Key attribute, but that doesn't seem to work anymore. Based on some googling it seems to me like you're best best is to create a custom control library of your own that has a themes/generic.xaml file that defines your custom styles. Then you can use your own elements that are styled properly (MyButton instead of Button). Either that or [stick with the Style property](https://silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/10/02/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-55-how-to-apply-styles-in-silverlight-part-i.aspx).

Some example of this [here](http://cynergysystems.com/blogs/page/josefajardo?entry=skinning_a_button_4_different) and an alternate approach using themes [here](http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Themes.aspx).

**Update:** Just found a really good example of this [here](http://www.ingebrigtsen.info/post/2008/10/13/Creating-a-theme-manager-for-Silverlight-2-Beta-1-Beta-2-RC0.aspx) (I think you might have already seen it :).

Answer (score 1):

To set up a theme for all controls create a Startup event and set the theme in the Startup event Handler. That theme will be applied all user control in that solution.

```
//App.xaml

<Application x:Uid="Application_1" x:Class="SampleApp.Home.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">

//App.xaml.cs

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new MetroTheme(); //Set your theme here           
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Einarl: Right now there isn't a way to "cascade" control templates/styles in Silverlight 2 core.  That is to say that you can't set a style/control template for TextBox and expect all TextBoxes to pick it up.  It is definitely something the team is looking into for future versions.